# Encrypt license string

Tags: vb.net, encryption, obfuscation, license-key

In my program i have a dll that i bought and in the program there is the license string.

The code is obfuscated before releasing but the string is not. So everybod yocould just decompile the code and read the string out. I need to encrypt/decrpyt the string. The question is not on how to encrypt/decrypt a string! Its now can it be done creatively in a way that nobody can get it back on a obfuscated code... Maybe by passing through 3 obfuscated functions etc.. any advice appreciated!

Comment: There's not really any "best practice" to be had here, since what you're asking about is security by obscurity. It will probably work for a less determined "attacker", but it's basically just a matter of making it hard enough not to be worth the effort.

Comment: thanks! so just enough obfuscated functions to hide it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a security design and not an implementation issue (you even note that you require no help with the coding). I suggest you try http://security.stackexchange.com, which might be a better fit.

Comment: *so just enough obfuscated functions to hide it?*
IMO this makes no sense - everyone who knows how to decompile the assembly will be competent enough to gain the original string.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem is not to hide string, for nobody can read it. 
I think, you want to preserve this string from modification, yes?

If so, you can keep string as is, but somewhere else keep checksum for this string, 
and verify checksum, when program is running, somewhere deep in the code. 
And exit, or do something else, if checksum is wrong.

For example about "else" - you can verify sum at each user input, 
and allocate 10 megabyte memory, if check fail. As result, "hacked" 
program will have memory leak, and difficult to understand, 
where leak comes from.